# Unity 5 Audio Volume Slider

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an slider that I can use for volume control in Unity 5 but the volume will not change.

My Game Objects are called MainMusicPlayer for the audio source and Volume Slider for the slider

I am going to post the whole script as it would be beneficial.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class AudioSettingsScript : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public const float DefaultVolumeLevel = 1f;

    Slider volumeSlider;

    void Start() 
    { 
        GameObject temp = GameObject.Find("Volume Slider");
        if (temp != null)
        {
            volumeSlider = temp.GetComponent<Slider>();

            if (volumeSlider != null)
            {
                volumeSlider.normalizedValue = PlayerPrefs.HasKey("VolumeLevel") ? PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("VolumeLevel") : DefaultVolumeLevel;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("[" + temp.name + "] - Does not contain a Slider Component!");
            }

        }
        else
        {
        Debug.LogError("Could not find an active GameObject named Volume Slider!");
    }

    }
    public void OnApply()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("VolumeLevel", volumeSlider.normalizedValue);
    }
}
```

The alignment of the code is correct in unity but it didn't like it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The master volume control in Unity is owned by the [AudioListener](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioListener.html)**

Your code is updating a saved value in `PlayerPrefs` called `VolumeLevel`, but it doesn't actually tell Unity to change the volume at any point. To do that globally (i.e. for all sounds at once), you can update `AudioListener.volume` with the value of `volumeSlider.normalizedValue`. By default, the volume is set to `1.0`, so you can only make things quieter - if the player wants more volume than the default, they'll need to turn their speakers up.

So, in your `Start` method where you read the saved value out, apply it to `AudioListener.volume` as well as the slider, and apply the new value to `AudioListener.volume` in the `OnApply` method as well.

Comment: how would I add this to my code?
Would it be as simple as making a variable AudioListener.volume = VolumeLevel?

Comment: You can update the volume statically, so `AudioListener.volume = volumeSlider.normalizedValue` should do the trick. You might find this helpful: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/172013/sound-controller.html

Comment: I got the slider working but It won't load the audio settings unless I return to the settings scene?

Comment: You're fetching the PlayerPrefs saved value in the Start() method of the MonoBehaviour, which will run exactly once when you enable the object for the first time (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html). Without looking at how you're using the object, I can't tell exactly when you're hoping to read the saved value and finding that it isn't working. If you want it to run every time you enable the object, you can move the code into an OnEnable() method (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnEnable.html)

Comment: I want it to pick up the saved PlayerPrefs value when I start the game and apply it to the volume of the music. Instead of having to go to back to the settings.

Comment: Ah, I see. You can move the code to set the current volume from the saved value into some other script that gets called when the game starts, and leave setting the slider from the current volume until you go into the settings.